# WPF: Binding not working on initial load, but resolves when edited while debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Button Usercontrol in WPF that whose properties are bound to inherited ones from a base Button class – all bindings work fine using RelativeSource, except for the tooltip text, which refuses to bind on initial load, but will bind correctly if the binding is updated manually while debugging (such as cutting and pasting the binding back in).

I have a feeling I’m missing something in terms of the DataContext (which I'm not setting manually in the button) but I’m struggling to find exactly what so any help would be appreciated.

**Button XAML**

```
<Button
        x:Name="IconBtn"
        Command="{Binding Command, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Button_Primary_Icon}}}"
        Style="{StaticResource Button_Primary}">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="Button_Primary_Tooltip" Style="{DynamicResource EditUserUITooltip}">
                <StackPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize_14}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource White}"
                        Text="{Binding ToolTipText, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Button_Primary_Icon}}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

**Base Class**

```
    public class Button_Base : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Button_Base));

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public FontAwesome5.EFontAwesomeIcon Icon { get; set; }
        public bool IconVisible { get; set; }

        public string ButtonContent { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipText", typeof(string), typeof(Button_Base));
        public string ToolTipText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ToolTipTextProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ToolTipTextProperty, value);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is Button_Primary_Icon?

Comment: Did you check Output window for Binding errors? Also vanilla WPF button can do all your code does, plus a lot more. Any reason why you are reinventing wheel?